# Create docker instance and then wait for requests

Tags: docker

I am looking at "dockerising" a neural network based comparison engine.   It takes quite a while to initialise the neural network but the actual comparisons are very quick.

Mostly when i see docker instances being started up they run a single process then exit.  However the overhead of continually reloading the neural network to perform a few comparisons is extreme.

Ideally the docker instance would be fired up, the neural network loaded and then sit and wait for incoming requests.

Is there a standard library or such like for firing up a docker instance that then sits and waits for requests to come in?  Such a thing would need to timeout at some point to shut the docker instance down if its not needed.   Its not the hardest thing to write but im sure there are plenty of corner cases and I'm a huge fan of not reinventing the wheel.

How is this usually approached?

Comment: Most containers run services that "start up and wait for requests": web servers, databases, REST APIs, etc. How do you want to your neural network to receive and respond to requests? Via http? Something else? What sort of data do your requests contain?

Comment: I was imagining something a bit more lightweight than HTTP(S) requests .. but i can definitely see that working ...